# Converting a factor to a numeric to then create a subset is not working

Tags: r

I am new to R and am having issues trying to work with a large dataset. I have a variable called DifferenceMonths and I would like to create a subset of my large dataset with only observations where the variable DifferenceMonths is less than 3.

It is coded into R as a factor so I have tried multiple times to convert it to a numeric. It finally showed up as numeric in my Global Environment, but then I checked using str() and it still shows up as a factor variable.

Log:

```
DifferenceMonths<-as.numeric(levels(DifferenceMonths))[DifferenceMonths]

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 

KRASDiff<-subset(KRASMCCDataset_final,DifferenceMonths<=2)

Warning message:
In Ops.factor(DifferenceMonths, 2) : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors

str(KRASMCCDataset_final)

'data.frame':   7831 obs. of  25 variables:
 $ Age                : Factor w/ 69 levels "","21","24","25",..: 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 ...
 $ Alive.Dead         : Factor w/ 4 levels "","A","D","S": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Status             : Factor w/ 5 levels "","ambiguous",..: 4 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 ...
 $ DifferenceMonths   : Factor w/ 75 levels "","#NUM!","0",..: 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. A `str()` isn't as helpful as a `dput()` for testing possible solutions. It also looks like you clearly have values that are not numeric in there like "#NUM!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, but you want:

```
as.numeric(as.character(DifferenceMonths))
```

The problem here, which you may have discovered, is that `as.numeric()` gives you the internal integer codes for the factor. The values are stored in the levels. But if you run `as.numeric(levels(DifferenceMonths))`, you'll get those values, but just as they appear in `levels(DifferenceMonths)`.  The way around this is to coerce to character first, and get away from the internal integer codes all together.

EDIT: I learned something today. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980780/7936744)

```
as.numeric(levels(DifferenceMonths))[DifferenceMonths]
```

Is the more efficient and preferred way, in particular if `length(levels(DifferenceMonths))` is less than `length(DifferenceMonths)`.

EDIT 2: on review after @MrFlick's comment, and some initial testing, `x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]` can behave strangely. Try assigning it to a new variable name. Let me see if I can figure out how and when this behavior occurs.

Comment: Your edit shows exactly what the OP is already doing. This doesn't seem to directly address the problem.

Comment: I ended up using as.numeric(as.character(DifferenceMonths), but I also assigned it to a new variable: DiffMon<-as.numeric(as.character(DifferenceMonths) and that seemed to work

Comment: Is there a way to then add this new variable into my existing dataset? So that I can then create a subset using it?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out and using this KRASMCCDataset_final$Diff <- Diff
Thank you for all the help